# How to prevent QML button multiple click in a short period?

Tags: qt, qml

I hava a QML button, and I want to prevent the button to be clicked before my function call is finished.

I tried the code below and it's not working. Button does not toggle enabled/disabled within the `clicked` signal. I guess the binding does not take effect immediately.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Control

Button {
    onClicked: {
        console.log('clicked')
        this.enabled = false
        do_something()
        this.enabled = true
    }
}
```

I also tried `pressed` signal

```
Button {
    onPressed: {
        console.log('pressed')
        this.enabled = false
    }
    onClicked: {
        console.log('clicked')
        do_something()
        this.enabled = true
    }
}
```

But the `onClicked` signal is not triggered at all.

Comment: Not a QML developer, but is `do_something()` happening in the main UI thread or in a worker thread? Cause if it's in the main thread, you should be able to click on the button again only after `do_something()` finishes. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: It's in the UI thread, and the UI blocks when executing ```do_something()``` in a very short period. But the enabled status do not change. User can't notice if the button is clicked or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I find the answer myself. User setTimeout like html/javascript for a delay execution. Since QML do not have setTimeout, it needs to add a Timer.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Control

Timer { id: timer }

Button {
    id: btn
    onClicked: {
        console.log('clicked')
        this.enabled = false
        timer.interval = 100  // a short delay, enabled status would change properly.
        timer.triggered.connect(callback)
        timer.start()
    }
    function callback() {
        do_something()
        timer.triggered.disconnect(callback) // don't forget to remove the callback
        btn.enabled = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If the `enabled` property binding doesn't work, you can always prevent your function from getting called yourself:

```
Button {
    onClicked: {
        if (this.enabled) {  // Don't allow multiple clicks
            console.log('clicked')
            this.enabled = false
            do_something()
            this.enabled = true
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

In response to your own answer to your question, I'd suggest an alternative to a timer is `Qt.callLater()`. It will essentially post an event on the event queue rather than call the function directly. That allows just enough time for other processing to occur.

```
Button {
    id: btn
    onClicked: {
        console.log('clicked')
        this.enabled = false
        Qt.callLater(callback);
    }
    function callback() {
        do_something()
        btn.enabled = true
    }
}
```

But I'm still wondering if you ever tried my original answer, because I think it's much easier, and it should work.

Comment: I've tried both of your answers, it can protect from multiple click indeed, and I thought ```Qt.callLater``` is more elegant, but they still have a problem. The button doesn't change to disabled state when user clicks, it blocks. Maybe that's my problem to execute long running function in the main thread. In my solution I add a short interval ```timer.interval=100``` to let the UI change. It works though not so elegant.

Answer (score 3):

You can enclose the button onClicked properties within if statement like

```
if (this.enabled)
{
// Do something
}
```

This if statement would not allow multiple clicks on your button. You can also set other properties within this if statement like what should happen if the button is clicked or unclicked.